# Background Refresh Not Refreshing

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, sharepoint, power-query

I am pretty new to excel/power query, so I apologize if this is a basic question.

I'm using an Excel 16 document on sharepoint that is pulling data from another sharepoint document.  The data queries just fine, but it's not properly refreshing in the background. I'd like it to pull automatically from the source file every day without having to manually come in and refreshing the data. Thank you for any help.

[current query properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cadP2.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Power Query doesn't work online. You'll have to open it to Refresh. 
The Refresh every 900 minutes only works if you have the file open in your system.